# New Facebook login guide

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook used to have a place where we can enter the URL after the user has clicked on the login button, but that seems to be gone on the new settings page.

Is there any guide available that is based on the new updates on facebook? I am building a website and would like to use the facebook login to get users login to the site and load their records from my database.

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7131666/get-user-basic-information-using-facebook-login-button-plugin

Comment: That's the return address your talking about, correct?

Comment: Yeah the accepted answer talks about subscribing to the auth.login event (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/), this will allow you to run javascript once the login is successful.

Answer (score 1):

Below is solution for your problem step by step :)

**You can solve your problem in 5 Steps**

**Step 1**

Create a new facebook app using the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and note its **App ID/API Key**

**Step 2**

use your App ID/API Key which you note in **Step 1**

The following code will load and initialize the JavaScript SDK with all common options. Replace **YOUR_APP_ID** and **WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM** with the appropriate values. The best place to put this code is right after the opening `<body>` tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  oauth      : true,
});

// Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

**Step 3**

Create a channel.html file with the below code

```
  <?php
    $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$cache_expire);
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
  ?>
  <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

**Step 4**
Add an XML namespace to the `<html>` tag of your document. This is necessary for XFBML to work in earlier versions of Internet Explorer.

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

**Step 5**

Once you have loaded the JavaScript SDK into your page and initialized it with your appId, you simply add the Login Button to your page using the div class element as shown below:

```
<div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
```

**You can read all the above in details where the almost all information is get below is the links**

1. [here you can get javascript, channel file details and other details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

***Thanks...***

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I put the button on the first file and also created the channel.html file as per your example. added the html tag on both files as well. 

but when I load the page, I only see the 'login with facebook' button, and when I click on it, it says "An error occurred. Please try again later."

Any idea where went wrong?